# Node.Js connect.use() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have been learning nodejs through a book and have tried to to replicate the examples given. However, I tried to create a middleware and in the book's example, they use this code connect.use(functionName).listen(3000). However, when i replicated the example and tried to run the js file, I was faced with this error: undefined is not a function and it is pointing to .use in connect. The following is my code:

```
var util = require('util');

function logit(req, res, next){
    util.log(util.format('Request received: %s, %s', req.method, req.util));
    next();
}

var connect = require('connect');

connect.use(logit).listen(3000);
```

reference: the examples is taken from Beginning Node.js by Basarat Ali Syed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`use` is a function you run on the app:

```
var connect = require('connect')
  , app = connect()
  ;

app.use(logit).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the answer, I forgot to add () in connect()